# c# wpf row definition

Tags: c#, wpf, rowdefinition

I need a help about some code. how can i split a row into two columns.My code is under this text.

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
```

so how can i split row 0 into two columns, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

and then to put your StackPanel in the first row and the first column

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
</StackPanel >
```

and modify the span if you want a control to span over multiple cells

Answer (score 0):

Put a `Grid` with 2 columns inside row 0 of the main `Grid`. Or, declare your grid as having 2 columns and set whatever you place in every row except row 0 with `ColumnSpan = 2`.